# Different hair dos & bhakti style of Krishna bhakts and Shiva bhakts?

Tags: scripture, shiva, krishna, rituals

I have seen that most all Shiva bhakts have long hair and long beard where as Krishna bhakts have clean shaven heads having long 'choti' at the center towards the backside of the skull.

Secondly, Krishna bhakts are more like into music, bhajans, kirtans whereas the Shiva bhakts are more into extreme activities like torturing of body for long hours etc.

**Krishna Bhakt:**

[image]

**Shiva Bhakt:**

[image]

**My question:** Are there any scriptures that point out in this direction or is it a mere tradition/ritual?

Comment: I don't think that it necessary for all Krishna devotees to look like that. That pic is probably of Chaitanya Mahaprabhu and he is having a shaved head because he was a Sannyasi. Similarly, all Shiva devotees may not require to look and dress like that. I think the pic is of a Naga Sadhu living in Kasi.(also note i am not the down-voter, and i am negating it by upvoting)

Comment: @Rickross thanks a lot, I agree with you. Also I too am not against down voting but the person should put forward his point of view before down voting so that person posting the question is aware of what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Its irrespective of the look of the bhaktha of God Vishnu or Shiva. That's Not important.

Simply to say there is no much prominence or importance of having out side looks of Shiva Bhakth or Vishnu bhakth. God doesn't care about it.

God Shiva and Vishnu one and the same similar to a person appearing in different dresses in indefinite times. The different dresses doesn't mean the person is different.

A vishnu devotee 'Arjuna' was looking very young with charming look during times with Krishna in Dwapara Yuga. The same devotee was appeared later as 'Thinnadu' in different look and blessed Shiva  by sacrifice his Eyes to Shiva. Shiva was very much pleased for his devotion and boon him as 'Bhakta Kannappa'.

Hence inner devotion is utmost importance for Shiva bhakth /Vishnu bhakth or any bhakth rather outside looks.

Comment: thanks for the response I get your point but that's my question, the appearance and style differ a lot so was wondering if there was any specific reason behind it? Even though it doesn't matter as the ultimate goal is same, but I guess Shiv bhakts have more stringent rituals.

Comment: Nothing like that. The rituals are performed reference to shastra and the dharmic way of tradition followed from  father and fore father and consulting from Guru. Vishnu bhakts also has stringent rules.... Example : Ekadashi Vratham, Dwadashi Vratham  etc. Like these many more are there.  The main purpose of stringent rituals are to put ourself in right dharmic path and getting more closer to god and keeping away from materialistic desires and material world.